# How do I properly reference resources using a basic Gradle project?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, resources

I have the following (rough) Gradle project layout (in an Eclipse project):

```
src/
 main/
  java/
   example/
    TextTransformer.java
  resources/
    transformMe.txt

 build.gradle
```

Roughly, build.gradle looks like

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Some API',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}
```

In TextTransform.java, I have something looking like:

```
    Reader  reader      = new FileReader("/transformMe.txt");
    Writer  writer      = new StringWriter();
    new UglifyJsProcessor().process(reader, writer);
    String  str         = writer.toString();
```

And I cannot read transformMe.txt. I've also tried `FileReader("transfomMe.txt");` and a number of other variants. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to be able to read a file from the JAR resources:

```
InputStream input = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/transformMe.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

new UglifyJsProcessor().process(...);
```